# Erlang: Identifying the max element in a list

Tags: function, erlang, max

I'm kind of new to Erlang, but here goes. I want to create an auxiliary function that takes the highest positive integer in a list and returns this value. My approach to this, in code, is as follows:

```
-module(function).
-export([normalize/1]).

    normalize(List) -> normalize(List, 0).

    normalize([], N) -> N;                                
    ​normalize([H|T], N) when H > N -> normalize(T, H==N).
```

I keep getting a syntax error on the last line (suspecting something is wrong with the guard) and also 'function normalize/2 is undefined' on the first line. How do I make this work?

Comment: `H==N` returns true or false, so if your code ends up calling `normalize(T, true)`, true is going to be 'asigned' to N (actually pattern matched against N, and because N is unbound, N will be bound to true)--not what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're comparing H to N (`H==N`) in the last line, but to fix your approach all you need is to replace `H==N` with just `H`. This would make it work for lists like `[1,2,3]`, but it would fail for lists like `[3,1,2]` or `[1,1,1]`, because the guard check would fail.

To fix that last case you need to add another function clause with guard check like `H =< N`. Building on your code, here is a complete version

```
-module(function).
-export([normalize/1]).

normalize(List) -> normalize(List, 0).

normalize([], N) -> N;
normalize([H|T], N) when H > N -> normalize(T, H);
normalize([H|T], N) when H =< N -> normalize(T, N).
```

However, there's a function that finds the max element of a list `lists:max/1`, and I highly recommend you take a look at its [implementation](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/lists.erl#L326); it is really simple.

Also your example doesn't include a list comprehension, so I updated the question title and tags. And one last thing, the name `normalize` is not kinda good for the function purpose :).

Comment: **take a look at its implementation; it is really simple.** I can think of an easier implementation: `max([Max|T]) -> max(Max, T)`. etc.